# Google Geolocation API - Use longitude and latitude to get address in textbox?

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation

I have noticed a lot of information about how to get your location using Google geolocation looks, based on IP address.  But I am wondering if and how I could use this service to input a location (longitude and latitude) and get back the current address, or at least a city, state.

I would like to do this in C#, but I'll work with any language.

Any advice?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you describe is called [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). Google provides a [Geocoding Web Service API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which you can call from your server-side application (using any language) [to do reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

For example, the following request:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

... will return a response that looks like the following (truncated):

```
<GeocodeResponse> 
 <status>OK</status> 
 <result> 
  <type>street_address</type> 
  <formatted_address>277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA</formatted_address> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>277</long_name> 
   <short_name>277</short_name> 
   <type>street_number</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>Bedford Ave</long_name> 
   <short_name>Bedford Ave</short_name> 
   <type>route</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>Brooklyn</long_name> 
   <short_name>Brooklyn</short_name> 
   <type>sublocality</type> 
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>New York</long_name> 
   <short_name>New York</short_name> 
   <type>locality</type> 
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>Kings</long_name> 
   <short_name>Kings</short_name> 
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type> 
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>New York</long_name> 
   <short_name>NY</short_name> 
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type> 
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>United States</long_name> 
   <short_name>US</short_name> 
   <type>country</type> 
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>11211</long_name> 
   <short_name>11211</short_name> 
   <type>postal_code</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <geometry> 
   <location> 
    <lat>40.7142330</lat> 
    <lng>-73.9612910</lng> 
   </location> 
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type> 
   <viewport> 
    <southwest> 
     <lat>40.7110854</lat> 
     <lng>-73.9644386</lng> 
    </southwest> 
    <northeast> 
     <lat>40.7173806</lat> 
     <lng>-73.9581434</lng> 
    </northeast> 
   </viewport> 
  </geometry> 
 </result> 
</GeocodeResponse>
```

However be aware that the [Google Maps API Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) seem to [prohibit the storage of the results](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12), unless the store acts as a cache for data that will used in Google Maps. You may want to get in touch with Google and enquire on the [Google Maps API Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) to have more flexible terms of use for your geocoding requirements.

Comment: Works like a charm thanks. I won't be storing the data, so that shouldn't be an issue.
Thanks!!!

Comment: @Daniel, is this google maps api free? limited access? Please specify. I want to make use of it not violating terms and conditions of google maps api.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a c# implementation. Please note that I am no c# programmer - so the code might be ugly. But it works. It gives you more than just the address.
This is a console application, you should be able to adapt it for webforms or winforms easily.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ReverseGeoLookup
{
 // http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding
    public static string ReverseGeoLoc(string longitude, string latitude,
        out string Address_ShortName,
        out string Address_country,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_1,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_2,
        out string Address_administrative_area_level_3,
        out string Address_colloquial_area,
        out string Address_locality,
        out string Address_sublocality,
        out string Address_neighborhood)
    {

        Address_ShortName = "";
        Address_country = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_1 = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_2 = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_3 = "";
        Address_colloquial_area = "";
        Address_locality = "";
        Address_sublocality = "";
        Address_neighborhood = "";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            doc.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false");
            XmlNode element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/status");
            if (element.InnerText == "ZERO_RESULTS")
            {
                return ("No data available for the specified location");
            }
            else
            {

                element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address");

                string longname="";
                string shortname="";
                string typename ="";
                bool fHit=false;


                XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        longname = xn["long_name"].InnerText;
                        shortname = xn["short_name"].InnerText;
                        typename = xn["type"].InnerText;


                        fHit = true;
                        switch (typename)
                        {
                            //Add whatever you are looking for below
                            case "country":
                                {
                                    Address_country = longname;
                                    Address_ShortName = shortname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "locality":
                                {
                                    Address_locality = longname;
                                    //Address_locality = shortname; //Om Longname visar sig innehålla konstigheter kan man använda shortname istället
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "sublocality":
                                {
                                    Address_sublocality = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "neighborhood":
                                {
                                    Address_neighborhood = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "colloquial_area":
                                {
                                    Address_colloquial_area = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_1":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_1 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_2":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_2 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_3":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_3 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            default:
                                fHit = false;
                                break;
                        }


                        if (fHit)
                        {
                            Console.Write(typename);
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            Console.Write("\tL: " + longname + "\tS:" + shortname + "\r\n");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Node missing either, longname, shortname or typename
                        fHit = false;
                        Console.Write(" Invalid data: ");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.Write("\tX: " + xn.InnerXml + "\r\n");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    }


                }

                //Console.ReadKey();
                return (element.InnerText);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ("(Address lookup failed: ) " + ex.Message);
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is reverse geocoding (See Daniel's answer).

An example implementation in PHP:

```
/**
* reverse geocoding via google maps api
* convert lat/lon into a name
*/
function reverse_geocode($lat, $lon) {
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lon&sensor=false";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    if (!isset($data->results[0]->formatted_address)){
        return "unknown Place";
    }
    return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private string getLocationByGeoLocation(string longitude, string latitude)
    {
        string locationName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(longitude) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(latitude))
                return "";

            string url = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", latitude, longitude);


            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
                    dsResult.ReadXml(reader);
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in dsResult.Tables["result"].Rows)
                        {
                            string fullAddress = row["formatted_address"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }


        return locationName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google's Maps APIs goes over http, so sending request with get and then parsing the request... It should be possible to do in any language.

For example, in PHP:

```
$ret = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" .
            urlencode($address) .
            "&sensor=false" .
            "&key=" . $this->key
    );

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($ret);
$error = $xml->status;
```

Same works for all APIs.

Comment: This is not an implementation of reverse geocoding.

Comment: I meant as example, how whole thing worked... Maybe I should've been more exact. I thought that just showing off how it actually works would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.calcularRota(txtOrigem.Text.Trim(), txtDestino.Text.Trim());
    }


    public void calcularRota(string latitude, string longitude)
    {
        //URL do distancematrix - adicionando endereco de origem e destino
        string url = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", latitude, longitude);
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(url);

        // verifica se o status é ok
        if (xml.Element("status").Value == "OK")
        {
            //Formatar a resposta
            Label3.Text = string.Format("<strong>Origem</strong>: {0}",
                //Pegar endereço de origem 
                xml.Element("result").Element("formatted_address").Value);
            //Pegar endereço de destino                    
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Text = String.Concat("Ocorreu o seguinte erro: ", xml.Element("status").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get an Address is through google's API.

For example.

```
using System.Xml;

//Console.WriteLine("enter coordinate:");
string coordinate = "32.797821,-96.781720"; //Console.ReadLine();

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + coordinate);

XmlNodeList xNodelst = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("result");
XmlNode xNode = xNodelst.Item(0);
string FullAddress = xNode.SelectSingleNode("formatted_address").InnerText;
string Number = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[1]/long_name").InnerText;
string Street = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[2]/long_name").InnerText;
string Village = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[3]/long_name").InnerText;
string Area = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[4]/long_name").InnerText;
string County = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[5]/long_name").InnerText;
string State = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[6]/long_name").InnerText;
string Zip = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[8]/long_name").InnerText;
string Country = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[7]/long_name").InnerText;
Console.WriteLine("Full Address: " + FullAddress);
Console.WriteLine("Number: " + Number);
Console.WriteLine("Street: " + Street);
Console.WriteLine("Village: " + Village);
Console.WriteLine("Area: " + Area);
Console.WriteLine("County: " + County);
Console.WriteLine("State: " + State);
Console.WriteLine("Zip: " + Zip);
Console.WriteLine("Country: " + Country);

Console.ReadLine();
```

P.S. be careful with different addresses with different components.

Answer (score 0):

reverse geocoding: get address from latitude and longitude using google maps geocoding api in asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetAddress("53.2734", "-7.77832031");
    }
    private string GetAddress(string latitude, string longitude)
    {
        string locationName = "";
        string url = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", latitude, longitude);
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(url);
        if (xml.Element("status").Value == "OK")
        {
            locationName = string.Format("{0}",
                xml.Element("result").Element("formatted_address").Value);
            Label1.Text = locationName;
        }
        return locationName;

    }
```